# Working RegEx that fails in Perl find & replace one-liner

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following RegEx `(<th>Password<\/th>\s*<td>)\w*(<\/td>)` which matches `<th>Password</th><td>root</td>` in this HTML:

```
<tr>
    <th>Password</th>
    <td>root</td>
</tr>
```

However this Terminal command fails to find a match:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/(<th>Password<\/th>\s*<td>)\w*(<\/td>)/$1NEWPASSWORD$2/g' file.html
```

It appears to have something to do with the whitespace between the `</th>` and `<td>` but the `<\/th>\s*<td>` works in the RegEx so why not in Perl?

Have tried substituting `\s*` for `\n*`, `\r*`, `\t*` and various combinations thereof but still no match.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: @Dalorzo: The `/m` modifier affects only the behaviour of the regex `^` and `$` metacharacters. Because neither appear in the pattern in this question it cannot make any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution is only applied to one line of your file at a time.

You can read the entire file in at once using the `-0` option, like this

```
perl -w -0777 -pi -e 's/(<th>Password<\/th>\s*<td>)\w*(<\/td>)/$1NEWPASSWORD$2/g' file.html
```

Note that it is *far* preferable to use a proper HTML parser, such as [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath), to process data like this, as it is very difficult to account for all possible representations of a given HTML construct using regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks Borodin. I see from the man pages that — **The value 0777 will cause Perl to slurp files whole since there is no legal character with that value** — However, I needed to add both `-0777` and `(?s)` for it to work: `perl -w -0777 -pi -e 's/(?s)(<th>Password<\/th>\s*<td>)\w*(<\/td>)/$1NEWPASSWORD$2/g' file.html`  Have noted your suggestion regarding an HTML parser. Thanks again.

Comment: `(?s)` shouldn't make any difference.  It only affects the behavior of the dot (`.`) metacharacter, which you aren't using.

Comment: @tech-otaku: No, my answer works correctly as it stands. The `/s` modifier makes no difference and is unnecessary. The same applies to the `/m` modifier, which Dalorzo thought was required

Comment: @Borodin: That's very odd, because without the `(?s)` it fails to find a match in OS X Terminal. Can't think why.

Comment: @Borodin and @Alan My apologies, your'e indeed correct. Not sure why I thought `(?s)` was required. It works as advertised. Some kind of brain freeze on my part I guess!

Answer (score 2):

Perl evaluates a file one line at a time, in your example you're trying to match over two lines so perl never finds the end of the string it's looking for on the first line, and never finds the beginning of the line it's looking for on the second line.

You can either flatten file.html to a single line temporarily (which might work if the file's small / performance is not so important) or you'll need to write more sophisticated logic to keep track of lines it's found.

Try searching for 'multiline regex perl' :)

Comment: Thanks Douglas. Would vote-up your answer but my reputation's not up to snuff!

Comment: No worries - I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use sed to do this:

```
 sed -i '/<th>Password<\/th>/{n;s!<td>[^<]*!<td>NEWPASSWORD!}' file.html
```

Another sed version:

```
 sed -i '/<th>Password<\/th>/!b;n;s/<td>[^<]*/<td>NEWPASSWORD/' file.html
```

Comment: Thanks perreal. In OS X Terminal this throws an **unterminated substitute pattern** error. I don't know why. My Sed is worse than my Perl. Thanks for taking the time though.